# GTK3 GtkLayout with cairo, cannot get update region

Tags: layout, cairo, gtk3

I am trying to draw a GtkLayout using cairo. The layout is huge and I need to get the part that is visible in the container window and update that part only. With GTK2 the expose event data was sufficient to do this. I am not successful with GTK3.

In the function to handle "draw" events, I did the following:

```
GdkWindow              *gdkwin;              //  window to draw
cairo_region_t         *cregion;             //  update regions
cairo_rectangle_int_t  crect;                //  enclosing rectangle

gdkwin = gtk_layout_get_bin_window(GTK_LAYOUT(layout));
cregion = gdk_window_get_update_area(gdkwin);
cairo_region_get_extents(cregion,&crect);
expy1 = crect.y;                             //  top of update area
expy2 = expy1 + crect.height;                //  bottom of update area
```

The problem is that cregion has garbage. Either gdk_window_get_update_area() is buggy or I am not using the right drawing window.

Passing the GtkLayout as follows also does not work (this is the function arg for g_signal_connect):

```
void draw_function(GtkWidget *layout, cairo_t *cr, void *userdata)
```

Whatever gets passed is not the GtkLayout from g_signal_connect, but something else.

================= UPDATE ====================

I found a way to do what I want without using GtkLayout.
I am using a GtkDrawingArea inside a viewport.
I can scroll to any window within the large graphic layout
and update that window only. Works well once I figured out
the cryptic docs.

```
scrwing = gtk_scrolled_window_new(0,0); 
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vboxx),scrwing);  
drwing = gtk_drawing_area_new();   
gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrwing),drwing);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(SCROLLWIN(scrwing),ALWAYS,ALWAYS);
scrollbar = gtk_scrolled_window_get_vadjustment(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrwing));
```